# Ошибка 404 в ubuntu при команде sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня ubuntu 18.10, amd64. Пробую установить что нибудь через apt. Ошибка 404 в ubuntu при команде sudo apt-get update

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У Вас что-то странное записано в файле */etc/apt/sources.list'. *apt* пытается достать оттуда URL на репозитарии, но ничего подходящего не находит, т.к. сервер возвращает 404 ошибку.

Я не знаю, какой конкретно репозитарий должен быть для 18 убунты, но вот у меня стоит *randoman*, для него проприсан такой репозитарий:

```
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse                 
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse         
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse        
deb http://ubuntu.randoman.ru/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, уже давно команда # apt update.
Во-вторых, попробуйте удалить эти репы и установить заново:
https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно указан список репозиториев. Подробно о том, как можно добавить корректные репозитории можно прочитать по ссылке. В статье указаны 2 варианта: 1) графический, 2) через терминал [https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/репозиторий](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)